# C# Replacing files with changing names

Tags: c#

I am trying to find and replace files however theres a bit of a problem. 
The files are structured like `PAVS_13001_0_I.pts`. The numbers `13001_0` change depending on the version. However I need to replace the files that have the string `PAVS_####_#_I.pts`

Please keep in mind there are many files that are named differently such as `PM_13001_0_I.pts`, `build.13.0.1.4.ClientOutput.zip`, etc. There are atleast 15 files like this. The strings should match up but the numbers will change.

How do I go about replacing files where the number values change?

Comment: What do you mean by _replace_? Do you want to *rename* them?

Comment: You can use a regular expression to match those filenames.

Comment: you need more Regex in your life

Comment: I want to replace the destination path, which has an older versions with the newer versions from the source. And no, I don't want to rename them.

Comment: Let me just take it clear: if their name conform to a rule, you want to move them to a new location. Is that it?

Comment: I was thinking of regex however there are many files like this, like I said 15. So in that case is there a way around of making 15+ regex statements?

Comment: What does this have to do with C#? If you want to "replace" files in C#, do you have any code of your own on which we can base our answers?

Comment: @stakx there is quite a bit of code to replace the files. However its just replacing files that are named the same

Comment: @user2619395 Please, answer my last question

Comment: @AndreCalil Thats exactly it. But just finding and replacing files with similar names except the number values will change. So essentially match everything except the numbers.

Comment: @user2619395: May I then humbly suggest that you restrict your question to the issue of identifying files based on a name pattern; and perhaps state your current approach to this issue (all via an edit)? Everything else (such as talk of "replacing files") doesn't actually appear to be relevant, but only raises uncertainties, questions, and perhaps even downvotes.

Comment: @user2619395 Is it the case that there is only allowed to be one file named `PAVS_....` in your directory?

Comment: @stakx Thanks, maybe that will work better...

Comment: @user2619395 Could you provide some feedback on my answer, please?

Answer (score 2):

If they're all in the same directory, you could try enumerating over the files in that directory and comparing the name with a regex, like this:

```
string[] prefixes = {"PAVS", "PM"};
foreach (string filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory)
{
  foreach (string prefix in prefixes)
  {
    if (Regex.IsMatch(file, prefix + @"_\d+_\d+_I\.pts"))
    {
      //Move the file
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thats the thing there are atleast 15 files that need to be replaced but it could be more. So it has to be extremly generic.

Comment: At least 15 files that fit the pattern, or at least 15 name patterns? If you have multiple patterns, is it a constant set? Is it based on user input?

Comment: Updated to use a list of prefixes. Could easily be a list of entire patterns, if it's not just the prefix that changes.

Comment: atleast 15 or more patterns, its based on what files are put into the source folder.

Comment: Do you also need to find out what patterns exist in the folder? I.e., look at the folder and say, "These are the file name patterns; for each of those, these are the files with that pattern but different version numbers; now I want to do x with those files"? I'm back to being completely unsure of what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
//appSettings section:
//<add key="filename-patterns" value="PAVS_*_*_I.pts;omg.*.zip"/>
string[] patterns = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filename-patterns"].Split(';');
string sourceDir = @"C:\from\";
string destinationDir = @"C:\to\";

foreach (string pattern in patterns)
{
    IEnumerable<string> fileNames = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDir, pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    fileNames.ToList().ForEach(x => File.Move(x, x.Replace(sourceDir, destinationDir)));
}
```

Note that you can change the last argument to `SearchOption.AllDirectories` and traverse all the tree. However, it will keep the folder structure when moving to destination folder.

I had these files on `C:\from`:

```
PAVS_123_1_I.pts
PAVS_123_2_I.pts
whatever.txt
```

And it worked properly.

**UPDATE**: I modified the code to work with multiple patterns. You may keep that list on your config file so you don't have to rebuild the app for each new file pattern.

**UPDATE**: now the code is reading from `appSettings` on the current config file. Just remember to add a reference to `System.Configuration`.

Comment: Per the OP, there are more prefixes than PAVS

Comment: This will also match PAVS_things_that_are_not_numbers_I.pts. Not sure if that's acceptable for OP or not. Search could still be used to pre-filter files, however.

Comment: @Michelle That's another good point. I'd like OP feedback about it.

Comment: It should match multiple patterns. I wish there was something to search the start of the string until it gets to a number value and then search the string more to see if there are any charachters. Perhaps that sort of logic would work? I hope that makes sense..

Comment: @user2619395 I'm sorry, but it doesn't. You said you had patterns where only the numbers would change. I'm presenting a solution that fits exactly that, even with configuration so you don't have to rebuild everything (I've just updated). I don't get what's missing...

Comment: Well i'll plop it into my code and see how it goes.

Comment: @user2619395 That's what I was expecting from you. Please, provide any feedback so I can improve the answer as needed.

Comment: @user2619395 Nothing so far?